# tee bash command with redirection

Tags: bash, tee

I have the following file:

file1.txt

```
geek
for
geeks
```

I am using the `tee` command to perform two operations on the output. My question is about the the redirection character after the first `tee`. I want to get the first column of file1.txt and
write it to file2.txt. When I run the following command, I don't receive an error but it does not give me the first column:

```
wc -l file1.txt |tee awk '{print $1}' - > file2.txt | sed 's/4/6/g' > file3.txt
```

However, the following command works as expected. What does the `>` is doing here?

```
wc -l file1.txt |tee >(awk '{print $1}' - > file2.txt) | sed 's/4/6/g' > file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> tee awk '{print $1}' - > file2.txt
> ```

does:

- execute `tee` with 3 arguments `awk` and `'{print $1}'` and `-`.
- `tee` will *create a file named* `awk`, *another file* named `'{print $1}'` and yet another file named `-`.
- Then the output of `tee` will be redirected to `file2.txt`
- `tee` will duplicate input to those 3 files and will output to `file2.txt`
- Consequently `| sed` will receive no input, because the output of `tee` is redirected to the file and the subshell outputs nothing.

---

> ```
> tee >(awk '{print $1}' - > file2.txt)
> ```

does:

- `>(...)`

  - Run `awk` with two arguments `'{print $1}'`  and `-`
  - ------  `'{print $1}'` is interpreted as a script
  - ------ `-` is interpreted as stdin (and could be omitted)
  - ------ then the output of `awk` of redirected to `file2.txt`
  - Then `bash` creates a fifo or a `/dev/fd/something` file
  - Then the output of that file is connected to stdin of `awk` process
  - And the `>(awk ...)`  is *substituted* for the filename of the file, most probably for `/dev/fd/something`
- `tee >(...)`

  - executes tee with one argument, like `tee /dev/fd/something`
  - The `/dev/fd/something` is connected to awk process on the other side
  - So `tee` writes to `/dev/fd/something` and `awk` reads the data from stdin on the other side
  - the output of `tee` is redirected to `| sed`

---

> What does the > is doing here?

The first occurrence is used to introduce a process substitution. The second occurrence is used to redirect output of `awk` command to a file named `file2.txt`. The third occurrence is used to redirect the output of `sed` command to file named `file3.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Process substitution is used to capture output that would normally go to a file

The Bash syntax for writing to a process is `>(command)`